# iPhone SQLite tracking scores in a table

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, sqlite, sdk

I have an sqlite table in my game that keeps track of scores.  How do I make one of the columns track scores in ascending order instead of descending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the data in the table itself is irrelevant, it's how you order it when retrieving it via a query is what matters.

In that case, in your SQL select statement, you can add the clause `ORDER BY "column_name" ASC` where `column_name` is the column you want to order by.

Answer (score 2):

The order your scores are saved in database is not relevant - you can specify the order you need in SQL query:

```
@"SELECT * FROM scoretable order by score asc";
@"SELECT * FROM scoretable order by score desc";
```

Comment: You need to add the `order by score asc` part to wherever in your code you are accessing the scores.  IE right now in your code, how are you accessing the list of scores?  Add `order by score` to that SQL query.

Comment: i got it. when i use desc, it works, but changing it to asc makes the scores not show up in the table....